# Separation of variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the heat equation using separation of variables

I have the following equation

http://s22.postimg.org/autrxs3jl/equation1.png

[image]

Then I factorized the equation into this

http://s4.postimg.org/w5s7ucxxp/equation2.png

[image]

Both sides equal the same constant. Then I work with this to find a solution to both sides.
I just wanted to know what would change if on the left side in equation 1 I added a constant? .. how would I factor all of the x's to the left side and the t's to the right side?

Comment: I have added the images you included as links directly in the text... it is possible to add images from the web...

Comment: It would be even better if you typed them as TeX.

Comment: If you added constants to the original equation, you could change that to the heat equation again via a pretty simple transformation. Then you'd solve the new equation and substitute back in at the very end.